# Python XML Parser that tracks line number in XML document

Tags: python, xml

Are there any XML parsing libraries in Python that track the line number of each element? I am writing a script to verify XML settings, and it would be useful to print line numbers if my script detects an invalid line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[lxml](http://lxml.de/) can be used to parse xml and retain line numbers. Here is a simple example:

```
from lxml import etree

xml = '''
    <foo>
        <bar baz="1">hello</bar>
        <bar baz='2'>world</bar>
    </foo>
'''

root = etree.fromstring(xml)
for bar in root.findall("bar"):
    baz = bar.attrib.get('baz', None)
    if int(baz) > 1:
        raise Exception("baz must not be greater than 1 on line %s" % bar.sourceline)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you really need to do is to *validate the XML file against an expected XML schema*. `lxml` [can do that for you](http://lxml.de/validation.html). The validation log would contain all the information you need to locate the problem in the XML file.

Comment: I'm not trying to validate it against an expected schema. I'm verifying that the attributes in my XML have expected numbers using my own logic. A simple example of what I'm trying to do: Check for all elements named "foo" and make sure that the value of the attribute "bar" within foo does not exceed 100. If bar > 100, I want to know the line where it occurred.